# Work done on person by escalator when person is climbing up the stairs

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, reference-frames, work

Suppose a person walks up the stairs of an escalator when it (the escalator) is moving upwards. What is the work done by the escalator on the person? Is it the same as if the person were standing still?

I think it is not the same because the person is pushing the stairs down, so the normal force must be greater than the weight of the person, which means the escalator does a greater work. I think that part of this greater work is converted into kinetic energy, since the person is moving with respect to the escalator. Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elevator has to perform more work in the moment the person is accelerating upwards, but then again less work when stopping at the top, i.e. decelerating. In total, the work performed by the elevator is therefore the same as if the person was standing still the whole time.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you are saying. I was talking about a person acceleration on a escalator, not the moments of acceleration and deceleration of an elevator.

Comment: So was I. When the person accelerates in the elevator (by starting to climb the ladder), it exerts a greater force on the elevator. But when they get to the top, they must stop and therefore decelerate again. During this time, they exert less force on the elevator and the elevator must do less work in order to move. And in the meantime, when the person is climbing at a steady rate, it makes no difference to the elevator.

Comment: But why is the force exerted by the person less when he decelerates? Ins't it the same as his weight? Also, assuming that the force is indeed smaller during the decelerating time, is it enough to compensate for all the times the person exerted a greater force?

Comment: Try standing on a scale with your knees bent and then stand up. You will see that at first it will show a higher weight (that is force on it), then if you do it slow and steady enough will show your real weight again and as you completely stood up a lower weight for a short time. Because you have the same vertical speed in the end as in the beginning (which is 0), the higher force at the beginning must exactly cancel out the lower force at the end.

Comment: so you are saying that every time I take a step, it is kind of like taking a tiny jump, meaning my body is not in the air, but it is not pressing the floor as hard as if I were standing still, and this reduction in force is exactly the same as the extra force that I exerted when taking the step?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Well, the force might not be the same, because you might do one over a longer period than the other. But in total they must match (that is to say their integrals), otherwise you would end up with a different speed than you started with.